# TeX Live 2016/Debian: BibTeX, Version 0.99d, References are not working

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, lyx, biber

I installed `Tex Live 2016` on `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS` using

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

Now References are not working. MWE is below with its output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{myrefs}
\begin{document}
\textcite{lamport94} is a good reference for \LaTeX.\\
Main matter with citations such as \autocite{lamport94}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

The contents of `myrefs.bib` are:

```
@book{lamport94
, author    = "Leslie Lamport"
, title     = "{\LaTeX} : a document preparation system"
, edition   = "2nd"
, publisher = "Addison-Wesley"
, year      = 1994
}
```

If I run other documents which was working correctly, I get the following error messages:

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016/Debian) 
>   The top-level auxiliary file: Test.aux 
>   I found no \citation commands---while reading file Test.aux 
>   I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Test.aux 
>   I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Test.aux 
>   (There were 3 error messages)

I also installed `biber` using

```
sudo apt-get install biber
```

But, no success. Even references are not working in `LYX 2.2.2` with its template documents. Any help to figure out the problem will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: To use the `bibtex` backend with `biblatex` you need to pass the `backend=bibtex` option to `biblatex`.  The generally preferred backend for `biblatex` is `biber` though - what do you mean by no success?  What did you try/where did things go wrong?

Comment: Thanks @DaiBowen for your comment. Yes, I used  `\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear]{biblatex}`, but still the same problem. I want to use `biber`, I thought it might be missing so I installed it but even after that, I am getting the same error. BWT `biber` is used in `biblatex`. Any thoughts, please.

Comment: Needed basics: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: @MYaseen208 You've got a TeX example but mention LyX: I'm not sure quite how you are working. In the `.tex` file example, running `latex <filename>` then `biber <filename>` should give you a `.blg` file: does it work and are there any errors?

Comment: Thanks @JosephWright for your comment. I am using Tex and also tried the same thing in LYX and both are not working. Any thoughts. Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you do? Do you run first `pdflatex filename.tex`, followed by `biber filename.bcf`, and then `pdflatex filename.tex` again? Do you get any errors/warnings in any of the cases?

Comment: Thanks @TorbjørnT. for your comment. I guess there is some problem in my Texlive 2016 installation. With `backend=bibtex`, it works fine but when I use `backend=biber`, it gives the following error: This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016/Debian) The top-level auxiliary file: Test.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file Test.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Test.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Test.aux (There were 3 error messages).

Comment: @TorbjørnT., I guess, it has installed old biblatex as indicated by LYX `Biber error: Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.1, expected version 3.2.`

Comment: About the first of those two comments: Of course you can't run `bibtex` when you have `backend=biber`. About the second: Right, so there is a mismatch between the `biblatex` version and the `biber` version. You'll need to update `biblatex` as you say. I don't know how to best do that when you've installed TL via `apt` though.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., Biber 2.6 is installed on my machine which requires Biblatex 3.6. But I think Biblatex 3.1 is installed on my machine.

Comment: I used `tlmgr update --all` to update Texlive packages, but it says `tlmgr: no updates available`. Any thoughts, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `kpsewhich biblatex.sty` to get `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.st‌​y`.
2. [From SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/) download `biber v.2.6`.
3. [From SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/) download `biblatex v.3.6`
4. Create two temp dirs: `mkdir tempbb && mkdir tempbl`
5. Uncompress `biber-cygwin64.tar.gz` and `biblatex-3.6.tds.tgz` to the temp directories:

   ```
   tar -zxvf biber-cygwin64.tar.gz -C tempbb/
   tar -zxvf biblatex-3.6.tds.tgz -C tempbl/
   ```
6. Move the contents of the files in the `tempbl` temp directory to `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/` thus:

   ```
   sudo rsync -azvv tempbl/ /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/
   ```
7. Move the `biber` bin from your temp directory to  `/usr/share/texlive/` thus:

   ```
   sudo rsync -azvv tempbl/ /usr/share/texlive/
   ```
8. Run `mktexlsr`
9. Test that everything is working fine.